# How to configure React Redux in Chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I built a chrome extension with react.js and webpack.config.js. Now, I want add redux to my project but I don't know how to configure with redux.

I just find the **reduxed-chrome-storage** npm package but I don't know how to configure.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to install the dependencies for Redux and the reduxed-chrome-storage package:

```bash
npm install --save redux reduxed-chrome-storage
```

2. Create a store.js file where you will configure your Redux store. In this file, you will import the necessary dependencies and define the store.

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import storage from 'reduxed-chrome-storage';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(storage.middleware)
);

export default store;
```

3. Connect your React components to the Redux store by using the react-redux library. You will need to wrap your root component with the Provider component and pass the store as a prop.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {/* your application code */}
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

4. Finally, you need to add the reduxed-chrome-storage enhancer to the store. This will allow the store to be persisted to Chrome storage:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import storage from 'reduxed-chrome-storage';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(storage.middleware),
  storage.enhancer
);

export default store;
```

This is the basic configuration for using Redux with your Chrome extension. You can now start using Redux in your application.

Comment: I got error for last step   in ./src/redux/store.js 7:2-18
export 'storage' (imported as 'storage') was not found in 'reduxed-chrome-storage' (possible exports: cloneDeep, diffDeep, isEqual, mergeOrReplace, setupReduxed)